# jquery ajax to temp div and then to live div on load

Tags: jquery

Ok, I have a ajax jsonp request that grabs a chunk of html and then tosses it into a div on the page. Trouble is, as the data loads, the content kind of junks into place (as it builds the html inside the div)

SO I want to load it first to a temporary off page div, and once completed loading, move the content into my main div.

```
    $.getJSON('getsomedata.php?jsoncallback=?',

    function(data) {

    if(data.success=="true")

    {

    // load into temp div


    // pause? until loaded?


    // move content into the real div

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you can use something like the following

```
//Will load a message into a temporary div
$('#temp-div').html("Temporary loading message");

//Will replace loading message with the server response
$('#temp-div').html(response);
```

The in your code, you would have something to the effect of (html)

```
<div id="temp-div"> </div>
```

This will also assume you are getting / sending a response from your backend. Again, this is an assumptive answer, but I hope it guides you in the right direction.

Comment: Trouble is I want to build the div off the screen so the user doesn't see things loading into the div, then after loaded, move to the view. Is there a way to wait for all the contents of a div to finish loading before proceeding?

Comment: You can "hide" the div, using something such as `<div id="temp-id" style="display:none;"> Hidden From View </div>`. So, rather than using the `$('#temp-div').html("Temporary loading message");` code, you would replace that line with `$('#temp-div').show();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback function to show the div on completion of the ajax request.

```
$.post('location_of_ajax_file',
    { 'post vals': 'with values'},
    function(data) {
        // this ambiguous function can also just be a callback reference
        // to an external function.
        // It gets called when the ajax request is complete, so you can load 
        // everything into a hidden div, then use this function to show 
        // the div like so:
        $('#hiddendiv').fadeIn(200);

        // fadeIn is cool, but you could also just set the css atribute to show,
        // or switch to another class that includes a show expression.
    }
);
```

If you really wanted to switch the divs, you could use the callback function to copy the html from your buffering div to your on-screen one as well.

Comment: .post works the same way as the other ajax functions, by the way, I just used it as an example. They're all just shorthand functions that call .ajax anyways, and all accept a similar callback for completion.